# Socket Hangup Error when connecting Oracle NoSQL kvstore

Tags: node.js, oracle, networking, http-proxy, oracle-nosql

I had an issue in nodejs, when I use the API link https://hostname:8089

```
  return new NoSQLClient({

                serviceType: ServiceType.KVSTORE,

                endpoint: 'localhost:8089'

            });
```

I'm getting error like this,

Error: [REQUEST_TIMEOUT] Operation timed out after 10000 ms and 6 retries; Caused by: [NETWORK_ERROR] Network error; Caused by: socket hang up

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the query, it's about the port, you have to expose the port first and then try it...or disable the firewall

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you are trying to access a **secure KVStore** using a non-secure connection call ( **http**://localhost:8089 )

```
NoSQLTimeoutError: [REQUEST_TIMEOUT] Operation timed out after 10000 ms 
and 6 retries; Caused by: [NETWORK_ERROR] Network error; 
Caused by: socket hang up
```

When accessing a secure KVstore, you need also to provide a user/pwd. If not, you will have the following error

```
NoSQLArgumentError: [ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT] TABLE_REQUEST: Illegal Argument:
Missing authentication information
```

Here is an example of a connection string (see https, if this value is not set you will use http by default):

```
return new NoSQLClient({
    serviceType: ServiceType.KVSTORE,
    endpoint: 'https://localhost:8089'
   , auth: {
        kvstore: {
            user: "driver_user",
            password: "DriverPass@@123"
        }
    }
});
```

In a secure mode, the proxy requires an SSL Certificate and private key. You need to provide the certificate, before running your application, set the environment variable NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS

```
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=<yourpath>/certificate.pem
```

Without the certificate, you will have the following error:

```
NoSQLAuthorizationError: [REQUEST_TIMEOUT] Authorization error: 
[operation timeout]: Failed to login to kvstore.  
Operation timed out, see the cause
```

You also need to validate the requested domain name to match the server's certificate.

```
$ curl --cacert ~/certificate.pem  https://localhost:8089
curl: (51) Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name
does not match the server's certificate.
```

In this case, you need to change the certificate or use the appropriate URL

```
$ openssl x509 -text -noout -in ~/certificate.pem | grep CN
        Issuer: CN=kvlite
        Subject: CN=kvlite

$ curl --cacert ~/certificate.pem  https://kvlite:8080
```

If your CN is not localhost, use an url matching with the certificate (e.g.)

```
return new NoSQLClient({
    serviceType: ServiceType.KVSTORE,
    endpoint: 'https://kvlite:8089'
   , auth: {
        kvstore: {
            user: "driver_user",
            password: "DriverPass@@123"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Dario. Upto this I've done and everything is fine. But, after this I got another error like ERROR: [ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT] PUT: illegal argument : store is not yet configured and cannot accept data

Comment: Can you share how the store was created? steps done during installation, seems that something else is missing. Is it a multi-node or single node deployment for tests?

Comment: It's single node for testing.

Comment: The same steps as mentioned in Oracle nosql document. I didn't skip any steps

Comment: I was not able to reproduce it.   can you share the output of the command `ping` and the output for the command `verify configuration`? if we cannot find what is wrong in your current configuration. is it possible for you to start from scratch with no existing root dir for your store?